# Starting Apache2 in Hera

Tags: release-hera

I'm running eOS 5.1.7 (Hera). I see that Apache2 is installed (`/usr/sbin/apache2`). However, `/etc/apache2` is weird; it only has two directories: `conf-available/`(javascript stuff) and `mods-available/` (dns stuff)

There is no `apachectl` nor does there appear to be a service unit for `systemctl`. I'm guessing that out-of-the-box, eOS/Hera does not have a full and proper Apache2 install in place. I don't know why eOS would only go half way when installing Apache.

To get a fully functional Apache installation, can I just (re)install Apache over this?

Comment: apache2-bin is a dependency of switchboard-plugin-share and gnome-user-share, both integral parts of eOS. This is not a full Apache server installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear to me what the question is, but you can easily install apache2 following any online tutorial for ubuntu 18.04

`sudo apt install apache2` should do the trick

`systemctl start apache2` to start it

`systemctl enable apache2` to set it autostart.

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-18-04

EDIT:

`apache2-bin` is a dependency of `apache2`, and, as stated  [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/apache2-bin):

> contains the binaries only and does not set up a working web-server
> instance. Install the "apache2" package to get a fully working
> instance.

Comment: The issue is, there's already some kind of Apache2 installed; /usr/sbin/apache2 exists as well as /etc/apache2/ (with files that make no sense to me). The question is, can I ignore the fact that there's already (a form of) Apache installed and just ... install over it? Will this break anything?